# bluetooth moduled couldn't get command and send response

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, uart

I am doing an embedded Bluetooth project using RN-42 and Cerebot MX7cK (a microcontroller board using pic32).
The first step is that the microcontroller has to send "$$$" to let RN-42 go to command mode, and RN-42 will reply with "CMD". 
I have successfully send "$$$" to RN-42 through UART. But I couldn't get any response from RN-42. It seems that the RN-42 just ignores my command, so it does not reply anything.
On the uer manual of RN-42, it says the flow control is disabled. But then it says flow control is enabled. I tried both way-with rts and cts enabled and disables. They behave the same way. In both way, I could send "$$$" to RN-42, but couldn't get any rely.

Comment: I'm using an RN-42 with an ARM at the moment and do not have to use RTS/CTS with the default settings. Most likely issue is UART set-up in terms of baud rate being incorrect or parity. I'm using 115200 baud, no parity. If you're using the eval kit it's RS232 unless you remove the jumpers to the FTDI chip.

Comment: I actually try both way-with flow control and without flow control. The one with out flow control, I configure RST of PIC is digital zero, and CTS of PIC is input. The one with flow control, I configure RTS is asserted(driven low) when the RX_FIFO of PIC has space. Unfortunately, they both fail to work! : (

Comment: Yes, but what have you set your baud rate to? If you set your RTS as permanently low and connect it to CTS on the module, then the module will always be free to send to you. If you monitor its RTS with a GPIO and do not send when it is high) you are covering the possibility of it having flow control switched on. However, I suspect it's more likely you just have the wrong baud rate or parity settings.

Comment: I have fixed the problem already. The default baud rate of RN-42 is 115.2kps. Previously, I set up the baud rate of UART of PIC is same as the baud rate of RN-42 which is 115.2kps. But it fails to work. On the RN-42, it has a jumper set up to configure baud rate to 9600. Then, I set up the UART of PIC to have 9600 baud rate. This set up works! :) I think the reason why it fails to work with 115.2kps is that it is too fast.